# Low-level differences between jointTrajectoryController and jointGroupPositionController

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm having problem when running servoing of a robotic manipulator. I can't find adequate explanation which could
explain my difficulties. When running robotic arm with MoveIt!, e.g. when I use jointTrajectoryController, arm executes motion
perfectly (schunk lwa4p), which could imply that position commands sent to each joint arrive correctly. However,
when I use jointGroupPositionController (which works in Gazebo), real arm moves only some joints and not all of them.
**I'm wondering how could I discover/figure out low-level differences between jointTrajectoryController and jointGroupPositionController**?

Thank you for your time,
Have a nice weekend.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381650/low-level-differences-between-jointtrajectorycontroller-and-jointgrouppositioncontroller/) by [**zozan**](https://answers.ros.org/users/77037/__zozan__/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question has very informative answers: https://answers.ros.org/question/356349/difference-between-arm_controller-and-joint_group_position_controller/.

Also, you can try using `JointPositionController` for each joint to verify that the joints are moving as expected.

---

Originally posted by [Pratik Somaiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/27312/pratik-somaiya/) with karma: 146 on 2021-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1